# RapidJson Object Array

Tags: rapidjson

I have a `JSON` file, which contains following information.

It is using array of objects. I want to retrieve name of **"TetaInfo"** object and value of **"cad"** object.

How can I do it?

```
{
    "data": "group",
    "name": "root",
    "objects": {
        "BOOT": {
            "data": "group",
            "name": "ProjectData",
            "objects": {
                "ModInfo": {
                    "data": "group",
                    "name": "Modformat",
                    "objects": {
                        "TetaInfo": {
                            "data": "group",
                            "name": "Tetaformat",
                            "objects": {
                                "Cad": {
                                    "data": "text",
                                    "name": "Cadingo",
                                    "value": "CadValue6.0"
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I am not exactly know your need. But you may try to use the newly added [JSON Pointer](http://rapidjson.org/md_doc_pointer.html) API in RapidJSON, which can simplify the code and do check the validity of the path.

```
if (Value* v = GetValueByPointer(d, "/objects/BOOT/objects/ModInfo/objects/TetaInfo/objects/Cad"))
{
    std::cout << (*v)["data"].GetString();
    // ...
}
else {
    // Unable to resolve the value of the pointer. Handle error.
}
```

`GetValueByPointer()` returns null when the pointer cannot be resolved in the document.

Answer (score 0):

d["objects"]["BOOT"]["objects"]["ModInfo"]["objects"]["TetaInfo"]["objects"][ "Cad"] ="

std::string temp2 =d["objects"]["BOOT"]["objects"]["ModInfo"]["objects"]["TetaInfo"]["objects"][ "Cad"].GetString();
printf("\ntemp2 === %s",temp2.c_str());

Comment: This will work. But how to retrieve the data  by giving the object name as input.. instead of giving the whole path of the value.(d["objects"]["BOOT"]["objects"]["ModInfo"]["objects"]["TetaInfo"]["objects"][ "Cad"])